# ScrollView on widget occurs error

Tags: android, widget

when i use scrollview for widget, it's not working..
it says like problem has occured on loading the widget..
can't i use the scrollview on widget or i did wrong for using the scroll view?
here is my code..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="3dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="sjfdiosjdfiosjdfoijsdfjisdjfosjdfiosjdfiosdjf
            sdjf
            jsdjfosijdfo
            sjdf
            jsd
            fs
            dfjsdfdfsdfsdfsd
            iofjsjofdsd" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="sjfdiosjdfiosjdfoijsdfjisdjfosjdfiosjdfiosdjf
            sdjf
            jsdjfosijdfo
            sjdf
            jsd
            fs
            dfjsdfdfsdfsdfsd
            iofjsjofdsd" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="sjfdiosjdfiosjdfoijsdfjisdjfosjdfiosjdfiosdjf
            sdjf
            jsdjfosijdfo
            sjdf
            jsd
            fs
            dfjsdfdfsdfsdfsd
            iofjsjofdsd" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>


@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);

        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout_copy);
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        ComponentName cpName = new ComponentName(context, EmateWidget.class);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(cpName, remoteViews);
    }
```

Comment: add your error log cat here

Comment: there is no error on the log.. i just can't see the widget by the messege says i've written above in my question.. it says problem loading widget exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ScrollView cannot be used for AppWidgets see [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout)

Comment: but i can see the scroll on gmail app widget

Comment: That's a list view. Above Honeycomb (3.0) you are able to use collections. If you read the documentation that I linked above you'll have a clear view.